# Trouble mounting Microsoft Azure network drive in Windows

Tags: windows, mount, azure

I've just setup Microsoft Azure account, and am trying to mount a file system in Windows.

I have created the file system in Azure, and can see it (and can actually browse to it and upload files to it from within Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer), but I'm trying to just mount it as a drive, and encountering problems.

Azure provides a PowerShell command generated to help connect to the share.  Running the script in Windows PowerShell gives this error:

> New-PSDrive : The specified drive root
>   "\xxx.file.core.windows.net\azureshare" either does not exist, or it
>   is not a folder. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-PSDrive
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (T:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Looking around, it seems potentially port 445 may be partially the issue, so I went to windows firewall and opened port 445 for incoming, and then the error in Powershell changed, to:

> New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct At line:3
>   char:1
>   + New-PSDrive -Name T -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\xxx.file.core ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (T:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Trying just "New-PSDrive" and going through the prompts, didn't work either.

Just for kicks, I tried the linux auto-generated command from within windows subsystem for linux, and after installing cifs-utils, I still get "the specified device does not exist"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much for any assistance.